# Google sheet Filter/Regex function to match string containing two or more strings in any order

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a data set listed in column A on another sheet called data. On another sheet I am using below formula to populate a cell when the user types in cell B1. I would like to populate only the filtered data. So far this works well if I search the text in the right order, but won't if the order is reversed. Can anyone help to incorporate `^(?=.*\bCream\b)(?=.*\bBetaderm\b).*$` in the formula to make it work?

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(data!A2:A,(regexmatch(lower(data!A2:A),lower(substitute(B1," ", ".*"))))))
```

The list of data is really long part of it is:

```
Camphor USP Crystal <= 2% + Menthol <= 2% in Betaderm (Betamethasone Valerate) Cream 0.1%
Camphor USP Crystal <= 2% + Menthol <= 2% in Betaderm (Betamethasone Valerate) Ointment 
Clindamycin HCl USP Powder <= 5% in Betaderm Cream 0.1% or 0.05%
Clindamycin HCl USP Powder <= 5% in Glaxal Base Cream
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could be more specific, or perhaps provide a minimal reproduceable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide examples of text you want to match (and indicate which part should match if you only want a partial match), and provide examples of text that shouldn’t match.

Comment: You said you need to match "two or more" terms. What is the max number of terms that would need to be searched at the same time?

Comment: Can you share an example sheet with the current and desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets uses [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) regexes that by design do not support backreferences and look-around assertions.

To get rows where both of the two space-separated words in cell `B1` appear in any order, use this pattern:

```
=iferror( 
  filter( 
    data!A2:A, 
    iferror( search( regexextract(B1, "^(\w+)"), data!A2:A ) ), 
    iferror( search( regexextract(B1, "(\w+)$"), data!A2:A ) ) 
  ), 
  "(no row matches '" & trim(B1) & "')" 
)
```

In the event cell `B1` only contains one word, the formula will get rows that match that word.

If you need to match more than two words, you will to add more criteria in the `filter()`.

Note that `\w` will only match `[a-z0-9]`. If you need to match patterns like `<=` or `2%`, you will have to modify the `regexextract()`.

If you need more complex matching, you can use `regexmatch()` instead of `search()`, like this:

```
=iferror( 
  filter( 
    data!A2:A, 
    iferror( regexmatch( data!A2:A, "(?i)" & regexextract( trim(B1), "^(\w+)" ) ), true ),  
    iferror( regexmatch( data!A2:A, "(?i)" & regexextract( trim(B1), "(\w+)$" ) ), true ) 
  ), 
  "(no row matches '" & trim(B1) & "')" 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`QUERY`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where) instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(data!A:A,"where lower(A) contains '"&JOIN("' and lower(A) contains '",SPLIT(LOWER(B1)," "))&"'",1))
```

- `where` to filter out rows
- `contains` to compare strings
- `SPLIT` and `JOIN` to create dynamic strings  of `where Col1 contains {string}` according to the number of words in `B1`